# How to type Sinhala, Tamil or other Asian languages in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-language, unicode, input-method

If you used Google input tools to type in Asian languages when using Microsoft Windows, you might wonder how to do it in Ubuntu...

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu already comes with a brilliant language input tool called **iBus**

1) Open Terminal and run:

> sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n

This will install, keyboard layout schemes for Asian languages.

---

2) Now you need to logout from the system & login back.  (Or simply restart)

---

3) Click on the **language applet** at top right side of the sceen,
and choose **Text Entry Settings** :

[image]

---

4) You will get a dialog like below:

[image]

You may want to change the keyboard shortcut shown by
**"Switch to next source using:"** to <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Space**</kbd>

Then press **+** to add your language:

---

5) Choose your language/keyboard scheme from the list, and click **Add**:

[image]

If you are a Sinhalese, I highly recommend you to choose **Sinhala Transliteration** layout.

---

6) Now open a text editor like **gedit** or **Libre Office Writer** and hit <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Space**</kbd>

Now type A,B,C... and you will get corresponding phonetic letters (ex: අ,බ්,ස්) of the chosen language.
You can switch back to English when you press : <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Space**</kbd> once again.

---

Additionally, here are some popular Sinhala keyboard layouts:
- [Sinhala Transliteration Layout](http://www.nongnu.org/sinhala/doc/transliteration/sinhala-transliteration_5.html)
- [Wijesekara Layout](http://www.nongnu.org/sinhala/doc/keymaps/sinhala-keyboard_1.html)
Other schemes are avaiable at [www.nongnu.org/sinhala](http://www.nongnu.org/sinhala/)